# OOP Refactoring

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, apache-kafka

The following script derives schemas from varied file formats. Can I get this reviewed? What would the improvements look like:

```
    def _null_allowed_in_cols(self):
        for field in self.fields:
            field["type"] = self._field_type_converter(field["type"])
            if type(field["type"]) == list:
                if "null" not in field["type"]:
                    field["type"].insert(0, "null")
            else:
                field["type"] = ["null", field["type"]]

    def _field_type_converter(self, field_type) -> Union[str, list]:
        if type(field_type) is dict or type(field_type) is avro.schema.ImmutableDict:
            return field_type["type"]
        elif type(field_type) is list:
            return list(map(lambda x: self._field_type_converter(x), field_type))
        else:
            return field_type
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `_col_type`

You can use a generator expression here to return either the first match or `None`:

```py
    # go from this
    def _col_type(self, column_name):
        for column in self.fields:
            if column["name"] == column_name:
                return column
        return None

   # to this
   def _col_type(self, column_name):
       return next((
        col['name'] for col in self.fields if col['name'] == column_name
       ), None)
```

## Checking types

Use `isinstance` rather than `type(val) == cls`:

```py
# instead of this
if type(field["type"]) == list:
    # do something
# or this
if type(val) is dict:
    # do something

# do this instead
if isinstance(field['type'], list):
    # do something

# or
if isinstance(field_type, (dict, avro.schema.ImmutableDict)):
    # do something
```

## When to use lambda vs function

In this statement:

```py
list(map(lambda x: self._field_type_converter(x), field_type))
```

You don't actually need the lambda:

```py
list(map(self._field_type_converter, field_type))
```